# How to deal with multiple items' states from FlastList( How to setState multiple items from the Array?)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

FlatList renders many `posts` data.

`Each item` in the `posts` has **liked** data and **bookmarked** data. (Whether user liked it or bookmarked it)

My problem is that how do we store many data for each item to the state?

Here is FlatList. (nothing special)

```
<FlatList
    data={posts}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
    numColumns={1}
  />
```

Each Item from renderItem, there is _handleLikePress button to change the `liked` state.

```
  _handleLikePress = (itemId) => {
    let { token } = this.props;
    this.setState({liked: true}) <<<<<--- HERE! 
    this.props.likeOutfit(token, itemId)
  }
```

! Development Point: I assume 'Like' feature works **100%** on server side so I'm setting `state` rather than redux' props.

**So how do we handle multiple items' state?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on this method this._renderItem  create a new component for each item and update each item its own state

```
<FlatList
    data={posts}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
    keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
    numColumns={1}
  />

renderItem(){
 return <ItemList {..props} /> 
}
```

inside ItemList component, maintain state

```
class ItemList extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      liked:false
    }
  }
  render () {
    return(

    )
  }
}

export default ItemList;
```

Comment: Wow! Does this work? This is so cool! And did you miss type {..props}??? maybe should we put three dots in it?

Comment: @JohnBaek its just an example you can pass any props

Comment: Got it. I got what you mean. Thanks!